# Maps inside a function won't let me return different type

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I am still new to TypeScript, recently I am trying to convert an js app into a ts app.

In my js app there is a function that convert all value to string inside of "Maps":

```
const convertUserDataToString = (dirtyUserData) => {
  for (const [key, value] of dirtyUserData.entries()) {
    const keyConvertToString = String(key);
    const valueConvertToString = String(value);
    dirtyUserData.set(keyConvertToString, valueConvertToString);
  }
  return dirtyUserData;
};
```

and I am trying to convert it into TypeScript(But it gives me an error):

```
const convertUserDataToString = ( dirtyUserData: Map<string, string | number> ):Map<string, string> => {
    for (const [key, value] of dirtyUserData.entries()) {
        const keyConvertToString = String(key);
        const valueConvertToString = String(value);
        dirtyUserData.set(keyConvertToString, valueConvertToString);
    }
    
    // ERROR: Type 'Map<string, string | number>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, string>'.
       // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    return dirtyUserData;
};
```

**So basically, the "dirtyUserData" that I am going to pass in to the function is going to be a `Map<string, string | number>` of key an value, the value can be either a string or a number and after the function ran, I want the function to return the same "Map" but the values are all converted into strings, this is the return type I would like to have: `Map<string,string>`.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `dirtyUserData` won't change however you edit the values within.

Since you're touching every entry in `dirtyUserData` anyway (and I'll note it's generally bad form to internally mutate an argument you're given), copy to a new map:

```
const convertUserDataToString = (dirtyUserData: Map<string, string | number>): Map<string, string> => {
  const newUserData: Map<string, string> = new Map();
  for (const [key, value] of dirtyUserData.entries()) {
    const keyConvertToString = String(key);
    const valueConvertToString = String(value);
    newUserData.set(keyConvertToString, valueConvertToString);
  }
  return newUserData;
};
```

Comment: ```and I'll note it's generally bad form to internally mutate an argument you're given```, sorry I don't quite get it, so it's bad practice to mutate the ```dirtyUserData``` data? but what is the best way to make sure all value inside of ```dirtyUserData``` is a string? sorry still new to coding thanks :)

Comment: Is there reason to convert key to string if you only accepts Map that has key type of string already?

Comment: @JustANewCoder Well, if the function mutated the argument, it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: @AKX So for "best practice", what should I do if I need to change the data inside the argument and return it? (With out mutate the argument)

Comment: For best practice, see my code. It doesn't mutate the parameter passed in and returns a new copy.

Comment: @AKX So basically for best practice, if I want to do something with the data that I passed into the function and return it, and with out mutating it. I should either make a copy of the original data, mutate the copied data and return the copied data or like your code create a new one, set old data into the new one and return the new copy, am I correct?

Comment: Yep. That'll save you a bunch of headaches later on - and you can also enforce these with `ReadonlyMap` and `ReadonlySet`. (Of course there could be places where you do want to modify data in place for eg performance reasons, but more often than not, don't.)